# bootstrap checkbox and label on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get my checkboxes and labels on the same line. The proper bootstrap way is to wrap the checkbox in the label tag like this-

```
<li>           
<label><input type="radio">Joe made the sugar cookies; Susan decorated them.</label>
</li>
```

But I'm using a CMS and it does not create checkboxes and labels that way, instead they are generated like this-

```
<li>
<input type="radio">
<label>She did her best to help him.</label>
</li>
```

The problem with this method is the checkboxes are on a different line to the label. I can set the label to **display: inline** and this works, but it removes all margins from my form and does not look very nice.

Can anyone help me to find a solution? Here is a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs04fqgo/)

Comment: You could set `margin-bottom` to `li` element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a little more work in the css... Just created a new fiddle for you.
[Here it is.](https://jsfiddle.net/9sx504m2/)

```
li > input {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
}
label { margin-bottom: 25px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:235px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Bootstraps's `radio-inline` class:

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xs04fqgo/1/

Wrap the `content` and `radio input` within a `label` with class `radio-inline`, then you can make it on the same line using `Bootstrap`

Answer (score 4):

Try using bootstrap "checkbox" or "checkbox-inline" class

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp