# How to have the checkbox and text appear on the same line in my code sample

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap text-truncate. In the following example, the checkbox and text are on separate lines. How to get the text right after the checkbox?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

</head>

<body class="body-bg-color">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style="min-height: 10rem; width: 350px">
            <div class="card-header">Hello World</div>
            <ul id="issues" class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-mine">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked></input>
                    <label class="text-truncate" style="max-width: 100%">Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi. Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting them both in a <span> parent

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: <span style=" white-space: pre-wrap;">
The other answer looks like the styling works too :)

Comment: I'd go with that one :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bootstrap checkbox and label on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795695/bootstrap-checkbox-and-label-on-same-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the **d-flex** class to the parent of your check-box and label

Answer (score 2):

## Wrap your input with the label

Since your label doesn't include a `for` attribute the label isn't going to be applied properly for accessibility users. You can actually make the input a child of the label. This will accomplish your goal, and improve the experience for screen readers, AND it makes the text clickable which is a common UX expectation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello World</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body class="body-bg-color">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card" style="min-height: 10rem; width: 350px">
      <div class="card-header">Hello World</div>
      <ul id="issues" class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-mine">
        <li class="list-group-item"> <label class="text-truncate" style="max-width: 100%">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked></input>
                   Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi. Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks John. It works. However, I have to make the input and label at the same level. The reason is that I implemented popover on the label. Making the checkbox a child will cause the popover to appear when clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flexbox on the parent div of both. I also removed the bottom margin off the label and some margin left on the label to shift it to the right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

</head>

<body class="body-bg-color">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style="min-height: 10rem; width: 350px">
            <div class="card-header">Hello World</div>
            <ul id="issues" class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-mine">
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked></input>
                    <label class="text-truncate ml-2 mb-0" style="max-width: 100%">Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi. Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```